# How to setup the initial value with framer motion useAnimate hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion, motion, framerjs

The motion component has an initial prop:

```
<motion.div
  initial={{ x: "100%" }}
  animate={{ x: "calc(100vw - 50%)" }}
/>
```

while using useAnimate with `useInView` hook:

```
const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();
const isInView = useInView(scope, { once: true, amount: 0.8 });

useEffect(() => {
  if (isInView) {
    animate('.anim-up', { y: [100, 0] }, { duration: 1, delay: stagger(0.15) })
  }
}, [isInView]);
```

all the elements jump from 0 to 100 at the first keyframe, how to set up an initial value?

Answer (score 1):

When working with `useAnimate`, assign the initial values in the CSS files itself. The value that you need your element to turn to must be then passed to the animate method. The prop `initial` isn't required when working with `useAnimate`. Also, it is best you refer to your elements directly instead of using classNames (as in, "span"/"p"/"div" etc.)

Here's an example of what your solution might look like (y moves from 100 to 0).

```
const [animationScope, animateSpan] = useAnimate();

useEffect(() => {
  if (isInView) {
    animateSpan('span', { y: 0 }, { duration: 1, delay: staggerChildren(0.15) })
  }
}, [isInView]);

//jsx to be returned:
    
  <div ref={animationScope}>
    <motion.span></motion.span>
  </div>
```

In the example above, the desired result can only be achieved if the `<span></span>`s have a `transform: translateY()` of `100`. Also, please note that the `useEffect` above will only fire up if the state of the dependency `isInView` changes (mentioning this as it seems to be a regular variable). Good luck!